# Find the probability that $Y > X$

Tags: probability

Let $X$ have a uniform distribution in the unit interval $[0,1]$, and let $Y$ have an exponential distribution with parameter $2$.

Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, find $P(Y>X)$.

Comment: There are two distinct conventional ways to parametrized the family of exponential distributions.  According to one of them, the density would be $2e^{-2x}$ for $x>0$; according to the other it would be $(1/2)e^{-x/2}$ for $x>0$.  Which one do you have in mind?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I have 2e^(-2x)

Comment: @Abramo I am not really sure how to start. If you can give a hint, I'd really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Let the parameter of the exponential be $\lambda$. Then (according to the more common convention of the two mentioned in the comment by Michael Hardy) the density function of $Y$ is $\lambda e^{-\lambda y}$ (for $y\gt 0$) and $0$ elsewhere.

By independence, the **joint** density function of $X$ and $Y$ is then $(1)(\lambda e^{-\lambda y})$ for $0\lt x\lt 1$, $y\gt 0$, and $0$ elsewhere.

Draw the line $y=x$. We want the probability of ending up above that line. Let $D$ be the region above the line $y=x$, with $0\lt x\lt 1$. The required probability is
$$\iint_D \lambda e^{-\lambda y}\,dy \,dx.$$
To evaluate the integral, express it as an iterated integral.  At this time, we leave the details to you.